# Slow mac after water spill

Tags: macbook-pro, damage

Month ago two things happened to my Macbook pro mid 2012 with El Captain, it fell down and I spilled around 50 ml of water on the keyboard and touchpad and immidiately wiped it out.
I don't remeber how much time passed after this accidents till the moment when my mac started to work extremly slow(1 to 3 days maybe). Almost any click provokes pinwheel. 
I ran extended Apple hardware test and it didn`t find any problem. Does it mean that water spill did'nt damage my mac?
What should I do in this situation?
I would like to go to service ceneter but I have extremly limited budget right now.

Also there no overheating or noisy fan. But I remeber that once it didn't go sleep. Is it possible that hdd cable is damaged?

Comment: I'd start with backing up and do a full clean OSX install (remove partition, create partition, install OSX via bootable USB).  If that doesn't fix your problem get yourself a set of screwdrivers and get behind the keyboard (ifixit.com has good step by step guides for that).  These 2 steps will cost you time rather than money.

Comment: @EDP I've taken apart the keyboard in my Mid-2009 MacBook Pro and it wasn't too difficult, but one may have to drill out some of the small screws attaching the keyboard to the frame.